# React - Error: App(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm creating a full stack application using MERN and GraphQL Apollo. For connecting the backend to client, I'm using Apollo Client. Here is the code -

ApolloProvider.js

```
import React from "react";
import App from "./App";
import {
  ApolloClient,
  createHttpLink,
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloProvider,
} from "@apollo/client";

const httpLink = createHttpLink({ uri: "http://localhost:5000" });

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export default (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>
);
```

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import ApolloProvider from "./ApolloProvider";

ReactDOM.render(ApolloProvider, document.getElementById("root"));

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
reportWebVitals();
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container } from "semantic-ui-react";

import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";
import "./App.css";

import MenuBar from "./components/MenuBar";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Register from "./pages/Register";

function App() {
  <Router>
    <Container>
      <MenuBar />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
    </Container>
  </Router>;
}

export default App;
```

At `ReactDOM.render(ApolloProvider, document.getElementById("root"));` error is coming as - 'Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.'

Can anyone please help on how to fix this?
Edit: Stack trace -
[image]

Comment: Is there an accompanying stack trace? This usually means that somewhere you are not returning a valid ReactNode from one of your component render methods. The stacktrace usually gives you an indication to which component is the culprit.

Comment: @JacobSmit updated in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: looks like the problem was in your `App.js` all along. You don't **return** the JSX of your app. Add that in:

```
function App() {
  return (
     <Router>
        <Container>
        <MenuBar />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
        </Container>
     </Router>
  );
}
```

---

*Original answer:*

You need to actually render the element in `ReactDOM.render`, i.e.

```
ReactDOM.render(<ApolloProvider/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Also in your apollo provider, return a functional component, not pure JSX. Not sure if that'd matter, but might help, i.e.

```
const ApolloApp = () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>
);

export default ApolloApp;
```

Comment: @GauravGupta ok there's your problem haha I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you so much @Jayce444
It fixed the issue ;)